# How change node-Sqlite3 default options

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

I am using sqlite3 in my electron project.

in order to achieve multi threading [I refered from official site](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe), 
they tells 
"When compiled with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2, SQLite can be used in a multithreaded program so long as no two threads attempt to use the same database connection"

i am creating database like this

```
new sqlite3.Database(
  pathname,
  sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE,
  err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('eror' , err)
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
  })
```

So how to pass the multi thread config in my code ??

Comment: Have you checked in node `sqlite3`  providing `multithreading`

Comment: I don't know most of us says Sqlite allows only one write at one time.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/  you should check more from here